# A stopping time problem for a random walk with transition probabilities dependent on states

Tags: probability, martingales, markov-process, random-walk, stopping-times

**The Problem:** In a one-dimensional random walk, at position $n > 0$, the probability of moving to $(n-1)$ is $\frac{n+2}{2n+2}$, and the probability of moving to $(n+1)$ is $\frac{n}{2n+2}$. Starting at position $n$, what is the average time to reach position $0$?

**Question 1:**
Let $v(n)$ be the expected time of moving from $n$ to $0$. Then we have the following recursive equation:
$$v(n) = 1 + \frac{n+2}{2n+2} v(n-1) + \frac{n}{2n+2} v(n+1)$$
And obviously $v(0) = 0$, but to solve the equation we also need to know $v(1)$, which I cannot compute.
*So my first question is: How to compute $v(1)$?*

p.s. Using random simulation on a computer, I have estimated that $v(1) = 3$. Then the recursive equation can be solved to obtain $v(n) = n(n+2)$. But I do not know how to compute $v(1)$ theoretically.

**Question 2:**
Another way to solve this problem is to use martingale.
Let $X_t$ be the random position at time $t$, and $X_0 = n$.
Let
$$Y_t = (X_t+1)^2 + t$$
then $\{Y_t, t \ge 0\}$ is a martingale with respect to $\{X_t, t \ge 0\}$.
Let $T$ be the first visit time from $n$ to $0$ (stopping time).
**If the optional stopping theorem is applicable**, then
$$E(Y_T)= (0+1)^2+E(T) = E(Y_0) = (n+1)^2 + 0$$
So we have
$$E(T) = n(n+2)$$
However, for the optional stopping theorem to be applicable, I have to firstly prove $E(T) < \infty$.
*So my second question is: How to prove the expected stopping time $E(T) < \infty$?*

Thanks

Comment: A way to pass the buck further is to cut the process off at some $N>0$, run optional stopping again, and then you end up with $(n+1)^2=P(X_T=0)+P(X_T=N)(N+1)^2+E[T]$. One can hope that $P(X_T=N) (N+1)^2 \to 0$ as $N \to \infty$ but that is not automatic. (Note I did not check that your martingale is a martingale.)

Comment: Note you can do the same thing with the recursion directly: redefine $v(n)$ in terms of hitting either $0$ or $N$ and then everything is well defined but returning to this problem requires sending $N\to \infty$.

Comment: @Ian You are totally correct! $P(X_T = N|X_0 = n) = \frac{n}{N}\frac{n+1}{N+1}\frac{n+2}{N+2}$. So $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} P(X_T = N)(N+1)^2 = 0$.

Comment: Well, I don't actually know how you showed that, but if that's correct then you are done. Glad I could bridge the gap.

Comment: (What I said also bridges the gap with your original calculation because it can't be that $E[T] \to \infty$ as $N \to \infty$ because there's no negative term on the RHS of my equation to counterbalance that.)

Comment: Have you tried **detailed balance** ?

Comment: @Ian I obtain $u(n) = (_=|_0=)$ by solving recursive equation for $u(n)$. And yes, I think the gap is bridged following your first suggestion.  I think your second suggestion on directly redefine $v(n)$ would also work. But then I find the recursive equation too difficult to solve for me. However, at least the martingale method works.

Comment: @C.C Would you please elaborate on the idea of using "detailed balance"?

Comment: @user1829077 How did you discover the martingale $Y_t$ ?

Comment: @YuvalPeres Well, I get $Y_t$ by guessing.  I first get the result $n(n+2)$ by random simulation in my Question 1. But I did not find the way to solve the recursive equation theoretically. So I turned to martingale method and optional stopping.  To have a $E(T)$, I define $Y_t$ to the form $f(X_t) + t$, where $f(\cdot)$ is the function to be found. Then $E(Y_T) = f(0) + E(T) = E(Y_0) = f(n) + 0$. So $E(T) = f(n) - f(0) = n(n+2)$. Then I tried the most simple form $f(n) = (n+1)^2$, and verified that $Y_t$ is indeed a martingale.

Comment: Thanks for explaining your thought process.

Answer (score 2):

You can introduce stopping times $T_N=\inf \{ t : X_t \in \{ 0,N \} \}$. Then using optional stopping you have $(n+1)^2=P(X_{T_N}=0)+(N+1)^2 P(X_{T_N}=N) + E[T_N]$. Now you can proceed in one of two ways:

- Calculate $L:=\lim_{N \to \infty} (N+1)^2 P(X_{T_N}=N)$, in which case you get $E[T]=(n+1)^2-P(X_T=0)-L=n(n+2)-L$. It turns out that this $L$ is actually zero, but the fact that $P(X_{T_N}=N)=o(N^{-2})$, which is required to prove this, is not immediately obvious.
- Note that by taking $N \to \infty$, the above equation implies $E[T]<\infty$, because the LHS is finite and the RHS consists only of nonnegative terms. Therefore you can use the optional stopping argument that you set up.